# Getting error in ng-repeat using angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am getting the below error while using ng-repeat in Angular.js.

> Error:

```
Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.6/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=ses%20in%20sectionData&p1=string%3Al&p2=l
    at Error (native)
    at http://oditek.in/Gofasto/js/angularjs.js:6:416
    at http://oditek.in/Gofasto/js/angularjs.js:279:39
    at Object.fn (http://oditek.in/Gofasto/js/angularjs.js:129:128)
    at n.$digest (http://oditek.in/Gofasto/js/angularjs.js:130:206)
    at n.$apply (http://oditek.in/Gofasto/js/angularjs.js:133:236)
    at g (http://oditek.in/Gofasto/js/angularjs.js:87:376)
    at K (http://oditek.in/Gofasto/js/angularjs.js:91:448)
    at XMLHttpRequest.z.onload (http://oditek.in/Gofasto/js/angularjs.js:92:462)
```

I am explaining my code below.

```
<tbody id="detailsstockid">
<tr ng-repeat="ses in sectionData">
<td>{{$index+1}}</td>
<td>{{ses.colg_name}}</td>
<td>{{ses.session}}</td>
<td>
<!--<a ui-sref='dashboard.profile({p_i:profile.profile_id})'>
<input type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-green' value='Edit' ng-click="reload();">  
</a>-->
<a ui-sref='dashboard.res.session'>
<input type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-green' value='Edit' ng-click="editSessionData(ses.session_id);">  
</a>
</td>
<td>
<a ui-sref='dashboard.res.session'>
<input type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-red' value='Remove' ng-click="deleteSessionData(ses.session_id);" >  
</a>
</td>
</tr>   
</tbody>
```

Here my requirement is while i will submit my form the data will suddenly display on the above list.Please check my below controller part.

```
var userdata={'colg_name':$scope.colg_name.value,'session':$scope.session};
                $http({
                    method:'POST',
                    url:"php/resource/addSessionData.php",
                    data:userdata,
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
                }).then(function successCallback(response){
                    alert(response.data['msg']);
                    $scope.colg_name.value='';
                    $scope.session=null;
                    $scope.sectionData.unshift(response.data);
                },function errorCallback(response) {
                    alert(response.data['msg']);
                    $state.go('dashboard.res.session',{}, { reload: true });
                });


$http({
        method:'GET',
        url:"php/resource/readSessionData.php",
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    }).then(function successCallback(response){
        $scope.sessionData=response.data;
    },function errorCallback(response) {
    });
```

Here when user will inserting the data first time into DB after inserting the data should display on the list but here its throwing the below error after inserting into database.

> Error-2:

```
TypeError: $scope.sectionData.unshift is not a function
    at successCallback (resourceSessionController.js:48)
    at angularjs.js:118
    at n.$eval (angularjs.js:132)
    at n.$digest (angularjs.js:129)
    at n.$apply (angularjs.js:133)
    at g (angularjs.js:87)
    at K (angularjs.js:91)
    at XMLHttpRequest.z.onload (angularjs.js:92)
```

Please help me to resolve those above errors.

Answer (score 2):

It caused by the duplicate values in your data `sectionData`. You can fix this issue by adding a track by with in your `ng-repeat` like below,

```
<tr ng-repeat="ses in sectionData track by $index">
```

**Update**

```
if($scope.sectionData != null && $scope.sectionData.length > 0){
    $scope.sectionData.unshift(response.data);
}
else{
    $scope.sectionData = response.data;
}
```

Comment: @ Abilash: Ok adding your code the 1st error is not coming but when database is blank in the table i am getting the 4 blank row.Let me to add my read from database code when page loading.

Comment: @subhra, what is this for `$scope.sectionData.unshift(response.data)`?

Comment: @ Abilash : it will add the just inserted data into the table.`response.data `will contain the inserted data from database.I am using unshift for adding the data in top of list at each time.

Comment: @subhra, ok. I think you missed to link jquery to your application.

Comment: @subhra, `array.unshift()` is a javascript's function.

Comment: But after adding at least one data in database its working fine and there is no above error.These errors are only coming when user is 1st time inserting the data into db.

Comment: @subhra, ok. just check whether your variable `$scope.sectionData` before assigning response to it.